# Why does the 2nd script prevent the 1st script from redirecting and how can I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, if-statement, iframe

Everything works properly EXCEPT the redirection. If I remove the 2nd script the redirection works. Is there something I need to do to get both working?

```
<script>
function check_frame() {
     if( top === self ) { // not in a frame
          location.href = "https://xyz.any"; // either the frameset or an error.
}

     }
</script>

<script>
function check_frame() {
     if( top !== self ) { //  in a frame
          document.body.classList.add('framed');
}     

     }

</script>

<body onLoad="check_frame()">
</body>

<style>
body {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
body.framed {
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need (*actually, it does not make sense*) two definitions of the same function. Just wrap up in an single implementation, like this:

```
function check_frame() {
     if( top === self ) { // not in a frame
          location.href = "https://xyz.any"; // either the frameset or an error.
     }

     else {
          document.body.classList.add('framed');
     }
}
```